# Cleaning cells with a VBA function

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a VBA function, `myFunction(),` that writes content in cells and when the calculation is done, it would clear all the data it wrote. (I want to call it from a cell with `=myFunction()`) To clear the content, I've put this line at the end, to clean up before finishing:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$9").ClearContents
```

The problem is that is that **it doesn't clear anything**. However, I noticed that if I put that line above in a subroutine, and then assign that subroutine to a button, the content will be cleared when I click the button.

When I run the code from the window of the program "Microsoft Visual Basic" (with the play button), the code works perfectly (the content gets cleared) but when I call the function from a cell, the cleaning part doesn't work anymore. 
Here is the code:

```
Function myFunction()
  ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$9").Clear
End Function
```

When I click in a cell and type `=myFunction()`, the content in the range $A$1:$B$9 is NOT cleared. 
However if I create a subroutine (instead of a function), and call it with a button, the content IS cleared.

Why won't it work when called by myFunction() ? How can I solve this ?

Comment: This is very commonly asked question. Search Google :)

Comment: Use ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$9").Clear

Comment: @Santosh: You cannot do that from an excel formula/UDF

Comment: @Santosh it doesn't work. Look at my edit2 please ;p

Comment: @user1493046 can you paste the code for myFunction

Comment: I think it might be a permission problem ; cf. edit3

Comment: If any one of the proposed answers solved your problem then you should "Accept" it for the benefit of future readers (and to give some reputation points to the person who took the time to help you).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why won't it work when called by myFunction() ?

A function, called from the Worksheet, cannot manipulate objects on the worksheet, it can only return a value to the cell wherein the function has been called from. I believe this is to prevent circular reference and infinite loops.

The loophole is that a function called from within a subroutine *can* manipulate worksheet objects, but that's probably not a good habit to get in to.

As a best practice, use Subroutines to manipulate objects, and Functions only to return values -- whether to the sheet or to a subroutine.

> How can I solve this ?

@Santosh's answer, above, should do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of UDF you can use events. Please put the below code on any sheet code section.

[**limitations of UDF**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/170787?wa=wsignin1.0)

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$A$1:$B$9")) Is Nothing Then

        ' your code here
        Range("$A$1:$B$9").Clear
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

The above code is like a workaround. It will be triggered when values in Range("A1:B9") are changed from excel interface.

A user-defined function called by a formula in a worksheet cell cannot change the environment of Microsoft Excel. This means that such a function cannot do any of the following:

- Insert, delete, or format cells on the spreadsheet.
- Change another cell's value.
- Move, rename, delete, or add sheets to a workbook.
- Change any of the environment options, such as calculation mode or screen views.
- Add names to a workbook.
- Set properties or execute most methods.

for more details read the link provided earlier.
[image]

Comment: I pasted the code, but what am I supposed to do with it? I need it to be run from a cell, but since it's a subroutine I assume it can't?

Comment: Ok, but I need to call it somewhere, don't I ? Because simply pasting it doesn't do anything..

Comment: @user1493046 Its an Worksheet_Change event and would be triggered when values in Range("A1:B9") are changed and any logic you can write in this change event.

Comment: ok unfortunatly the event is not triggered. Thanks for helping man ;p

Comment: @user1493046 i have updated the answer with a screenshot. I hope it helps.

Comment: It works when I add the data manually in the cells of the range. However I use a web query to fill these cells, and in that case the event doesn't get triggered. Thanks for yout time man ;p

Comment: + 1 for suggesting an alternative :) @user1493046: Please see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/ms-excel-crashes-when-vba-code-runs/13861640#13861640) to avoid possible endless loop